# Sencha emptyText not showing

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am using Sencha Touch 2.4.1 for an app. The emptyText is not showing on the list and when I debugged through Safari, I see that an incorrect style has been applied on the div containing the emptyText div.Applied style is :

```
<div class ="x-unsized x-list-emptytext x-layout-fit-item x-has-height" id="ext-component-16" style>
           <div class="x-innerhtml" id="ext-element-140">No Favorites</div>

</div>
```

The way I am loading my data is I am making an AJAX call, getting the array of the results and setting that array on the Store , which is bound to the list. I have tried setting the empty-text both programmatically and in the Architect.

Any pointer towards solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to see initialConfig using Ext.getCmp('ext-component-16')

Comment: make deferEmptyText:false, then it will work

Comment: I have tried deferEmptyText:false too, that unfortunately didnt solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue was that there was no layout set on the container on which the list was housed. When I added a layout , the empty text showed up.